# I have written this code for json in python and i am getting this error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"

Tags: python, json, spyder

My code :

```
import json

a='''
{

     "abc" : "2",
     "phone" : {
      "ss" : "22"
      },
     "def" : "5" ,
     
}'''

info = json.loads(a)

print("Number", info["abc"])
```

It is giving me this error:

```
"JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"
```

I tried removing the comma but then it gives  me the error

```
"JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter"
```

Comment: It's not legal to have a trailing `,` on the end. Having that comma means that the parser expects there to be another key later.

Comment: That string isn't valid JSON because of the comma at the end of the key/value list. Unlike python, JSON abhores trailing commas.

Comment: Thanks but i saw a similar code in my python course and he has used comma at the end but it works fine for him

Comment: @tdelaney I have edited the question can you please help me

Comment: You have the same problem with a trailing comma. That is valid python (`ast.literal_eval(a)` would work) but not JSON. Remember that JSON is usually computer generated and its strict about format on purpose. JSON serializers need to be sticklers for details and that means that humans typing JSON need to be too.

Comment: @Jayshah, compare to https://ideone.com/0wIeNv, which removes only the specific comma that shouldn't be there, and works fine.